# Monitor.TryEnter to check if object is already locked?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a number of worker threads that call a common function. I use a lock object as follows:

```
static object var mylock = new object();

public void myFunction()
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(mylock, 0))
    {
        try
        {
           // Do work
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(mylock);
        }
    }
}
```

However, before entering myFunction, I would like to know if the object is locked so that I can do something else. So I did:

```
    public bool IsLocked
    {
        get { return !Monitor.TryEnter(locker); }
    }
```

Will this work, or is it locking the object?

Comment: It's locking the object if it succeeds. There's no point checking to see if the object is locked before trying to lock because it might get locked between checking and locking it. Hence ... TryEnter.

Comment: Is there a way to just check if the object is locked?

Comment: There's little point because that information is not really useful. If it's not locked and you go ahead and call TryEnter thinking it will succeed then you might be wrong because of the race condition.

Comment: Yes, that takes the lock if it succeeds. Also: even if it is locked, the thread that owns the lock will always report success due to re-entrancy. But ta.speot's point is a correct and more serious one.

Comment: And that's the whole point.  If there were something like Monitor.IsLocked(object), then it's entirely possible that in between you calling that code to check for a lock being taken, and your next code statement, another thread could come along and take a lock on that object, invalidating your initial check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will lock the object if it isn't locked, and won't release the lock until you call exit. If the lock is already taken by another thread it won't acquire the lock, but if you're making the call on the thread that acquired the lock in the first place then `TryEnter` will succeed.

To get around this you could use a flag and the interlocked functions:

```
object var mylock = new object();
long isLocked;

public void myFunction()
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(mylock, 0))
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref isLocked, 1);
        try
        {
           // Do work
        }
        finally
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref isLocked, 0);
            Monitor.Exit(mylock);
        }
    }
}

public bool IsLocked
{
    get { return Interlocked.Read(ref isLocked)==0; }
}
```